# Can't merge dataframes because of index type mismatch

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have loaded some data from CSV files into two dataframes, `X` and `Y` that I intend to perform some analysis on. After cleaning them up a bit I can see that the indexes of my dataframes appear to match (they're just sequential numbers), except one has index with type `object` and the other has index with type `int64`. Please see attached image for a clearer idea of what I'm talking about.[image: dataframe index error]

I have tried manually altering this using `X.index.astype('int64')` and also `X.reindex(Y.index)` but neither seem to do anything here. Could anyone suggest anything?

Edit: Adding some additional info in case it is helpful. `X` was imported as row data from the csv file and transposed whereas `Y` was imported directly with the index set from the first column of the csv file.

Comment: Can you show the code where you have tried `X.index.astype('int64')` ?

Comment: Yep. I will do so now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've realised what I've done and it was pretty dumb. I should have written

```py
X.index = X.index.astype('int64')
```

instead of just

```py
X.index.astype('int64')
```

Oh well, the more you know.